# .on('click', function(){}) only working on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click

I'm making a Blackjack game to exercise my Javascript skills. I had a bunch of `alert()` messages tied to the betting function to prevent invalid entries. In updating the code to have a more elegant message style than a browser alert, I wrote a function called `alertModal()` that pops up a message on the screen and then fades away. The message pops up the first time a user tries to enter an invalid bet, but does not pop up any other messages if the bet is invalid-- nothing happens. I know the `placeBet()` function is still running when the user clicks again, because if the bet is valid, `dealFirstCards()` runs and the game proceeds. So it seems to me that for some reason, the if/else portion of the `placeBet()` function is only running on the first click...

The game is live and running with this code at http://cnb-blackjack.netlify.com/game.html

Here is the javascript code in question:

```
// Player places a bet
    $('div.bet').on('click', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('glow');
        $('.bet-button').addClass('glow');
    });
    $('.bet-button').on('click', function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!placeBet.called) {
            placeBet();
        }
    });

// PLACE BET
    function placeBet() {
        var $bet = parseInt($('.bet-input').val())
        var $bank = parseInt($('.player-bank').text())
        var $currentBet = $('.current-bet');
        if (!isNaN($bet) && $bet <= $bank && $bet !== 0) {
            $currentBet.text(' $' + $bet);
            $('.bet input[type="text"]').val('');
            $('.place-bet .hideaway').slideUp();
            $('.player-bank').text($bank - $bet);
            placeBet.called = true;
            dealFirstCards();
        } else if ($bet > $bank) {
            var $message = 'Bet cannot exceed the amount in your Bank!';
            alertModal($message);
        } else if (isNaN($bet)) {
            var $message = 'Enter a number, without "$".';
            alertModal($message);
        } else if ($bet === 0) {
            var $message = "Betting nothing won't get you very far...";
            alertModal($message);
        }
    }

// SHOW MODAL
    function alertModal(message) {
        $popUp = $('.alert-message');
        $('.modal').removeClass('hide');
        $popUp.text(message);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.modal').fadeOut(1000);
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: Seeing the code for `alertModal` would be helpful.

Comment: .fadeOut is leaving alertModal invisible.  Perhaps a .show would fix it?

Comment: _"The [`.fadeOut()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) method animates the opacity of the matched elements. Once the opacity reaches 0, **the `display` style property is set to `none`**, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function alertModal(message) {

        $popUp = $('.alert-message');
        $('.modal').show();
        $popUp.text(message);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.modal').fadeOut(1000);
        }, 1000);
    }
```

As comments have explained, fadeOut is leaving the modal hidden after the first time it's clicked. Just call $(element).show(); on the modal to show it again and let fadeOut remove it.